# ArrayList<X> works as a key in a HashMap, but array of X[] doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays, collections, hashmap

I run into this problem when i tried to put the array and arraylist as keys in a Map.
First piece of code:

```
        LinkedHashMap<ArrayList<String>, String> lhm = new LinkedHashMap<ArrayList<String>, String>();
    for (int i =0;i < strs.length; i++){
        ArrayList<String> arr = new 
            ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strs[i].toLowerCase().split(" "))); 
        Collections.sort(arr);
        lhm.put(arr, strs[i]);
    }
```

Second piece of code：

```
LinkedHashMap<String[], String> lhm = new LinkedHashMap<String[], String>();
for (int i =0;i < strs.length; i++){
    String[] str = strs[i].toLowerCase().split(" ");
        Arrays.sort(str);
        System.out.println("***********");
        for (String strin :str)
        {
            System.out.println(strin);
        }
        System.out.println("***********");
        lhm.put(str, strs[i]);
    }
```

The first piece of code works as expected that whenever i put a duplicate key(Arraylist as key of same content), it override the value of previous key. 
But the second piece doesnt works as expected. it just put all the value in it.
Can anybody explain how this work? 
And is it a good practice to put Array/ArrayList(or maybe collections as key)?

Comment: Using a mutable object as a key in a map is rarely a good idea...

Comment: I don't know what do you want to earn, can you be more specific? If you want same key with different values you can use Multimap of Guava library.

Comment: @pst: yes, that is true, I believe.  But i just wanna be "lazy" once, so instead of using "array.toString" as key, I put the array itself.

Comment: @Martin: I just put the array and arraylist as key(which is not a good practice, I believe). And arraylist as a key works fine, but array doesnt.

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` already gives you a `List`, you don't need to create a new `ArrayList`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays in Java use the default equals method inherited from Object. Ditto on the hashCode method. So even if your putting arrays with the same elements as keys, you will end up with 'duplicates'. Lists on the other hand, override the hashcode method, to return values more representative of their contents.

In any case, it's generally a bad idea to use a mutable object as a key in a hashmap, though in some cases it's unavoidable. Using collections as keys in particular can trip you up in multiple ways;

- Adding elements to the list
- Mutating objects in the list, in a way in which their hashCode/equality contract change

Comment: @pst - agreed. It's the verb in this case that's the problem, not the noun. I toned down the 'rhetoric' some.

Comment: @Perception ok, the array doesnt override the hashcode() and equals() function. so, Map thinks they are different keys. got it.thanks